# Why Left() returns to 0, but substring () not

Tags: mysql

A Practice Q from HackerRank. Very confused about the difference between left() and substring () in the case: 
Reference: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem
Considering the following, it is returned to Name(0)

```
SELECT CONCAT (NAME,'(',LEFT('Occupation',1),')') 
   FROM OCCUPATIONS 
   ORDER BY NAME
```

but the following is correct

```
SELECT CONCAT (NAME,'(',substring('Occupation',1,1),')') 
   FROM OCCUPATIONS 
   ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: Both queries work fine if you remove the single quotes around `Occupation`. They shouldn't be there as you want `Occupation` to be a column name, not a string. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdav2qu5CgHhhbinZxvpA4/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct. `'Occupation'` (with single quotes) is the string that starts with the letter `O`, which is what *both* of your examples should yield.

You want `"OCCUPATION"` (with double quotes) or more commonly `OCCUPATION` (with no quotes) instead, which is a column name.

`LEFT(..., 1)` and `SUBSTRING(..., 1, 1)` are equivalent; your error is elsewhere.